# Downgrade Galaxy S Duos from ICS to Gingerbread

Tags: downgrade, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I want to downgrade my Galaxy S Duos from ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich) 4.0 to Gingerbread. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy S Duos was released with the ICS onboard and there is no Gingerbread available for this model. You shouldn't use a firmware designed for other devices from the Galaxy family - this is an easy way to brick you phone.

"Getting Prepared" instruction is irrelevant.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange and thanks for your contribution. For a free badge, read this link (http://android.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

## Getting Prepared

The firmware downgrade drill for the Samsung Galaxy devices is not much complicated as compared to the phones manufactured by other brands. It requires you to boot the device first into Download/Odin Mode, and then into Android Recovery Mode. I hope many of you would be acquainted with both the methods. Even if you are not, it doesn’t matter.

- Download the downgrade firmware for your Samsung Galaxy device and extract it on your computer. A good source to download Samsung firmwares is [Samsung-Updates](http://samsung-updates.com/). Type your device name in the search box at the sidebar, you would find it hopefully. If you do not get it, let me know (your device and country). To find out the correct firmware you can Use [CSC Codes](http://droidviews.com/2012/how-to-change-csc-in-samsung-galaxy-phones/).
- Download and install [Samsung USB Drivers](http://droidviews.com/2012/android-usb-drivers-samsung-motorola-sony-lg-zte-htc-asus-huawei-acer/) on your computer. Skip this step if you already have it.
- Download Odin Firmware flasher and unzip it (if you get any error with Odin3 1.85, try the greater version): [Odin3_v1.85.Zip](http://d-h.st/M14)   or   Odin3_v3.04.Zip
- Since the downgrading procedure will delete all data stored on the internal SD Card of your Galaxy device it will be better to backup your messages, contacts and installed apps.
- Charge your device’s battery to the full
  Make sure that you have turned on USB Debugging from `Settings => Developer Options`.

---

### Installing the Downgrade Firmware

Installing a firmware version that is lower than the current one is just the same as installing a higher one, but you have to one more thing that you do not usually do. I assume that you have already done as described above, so let’s go ahead.

- Turn off your Samsung Galaxy device whether it a phone or tablet and boot into Download/Odin Mode. If it is a phone, you can enter the Download Mode doing this: Press and hold the `Volume Down`+`Home` buttons together and then long press the `Power` Button till the screen turns up. Now press the `Volume Up` key to enter the Download Mode. In case you have a Galaxy Tab device, do this: Press and hold the `Volume Up`+`Power` buttons together, and then press the `Volume Up` key when prompted.
- Now go to the Odin folder and run the .exe file there.
- This is the time, you have to connect you device to the computer using a compatible USB cable.
- When the connection between the device and computer is established, the ID:COM port at Odin will turn to Yellow or light Blue (depending on the Odin version you are using) and you’ll see **Added!!** text in the message box below.
- Make sure that only *F. Reset Time* option is checked on Odin. The *Auto Reboot* option is checked by default, so please uncheck it.
  Okay, now click on the PDA button on Odin and select the firmware file in tar.md5 format.
- Now click the **Start** button on Odin. This will initiate the firmware installation. Wait till it finishes.
- Finally when you get a **PASS!!** message on Odin, remove the USB Cable from your device.
- Now open the back panel of your device and pull out the battery. Wait for about 60 seconds and reinsert the battery back to its place.
- Now reboot your phone into Android Recovery mode. If you have a smartphone, you can do it this way: press and hold the `Volume Up`+`Home` buttons together and then hold the Power button till the screen turns up and the Samsung logo blinks for two times. Release the `Power` button but keep the other two keys pressed till you see a black screen with green Android bot and Blue text. In case you got  a  Galaxy Tab or Note 10.1, press and hold the `Volume Down`+`Power` keys together for a few seconds till you see the yellow triangle with Android bot followed by a black screen with blue text.
- In the Recovery mode you will have to use the `Volume Up`/`Volume Down` keys to scroll up or down, and the `Power` button to select an option.
- So, scroll down to wipe *data/factory reset* option and select *yes* to confirm your choice.
- Now go to *wipe cache partition* and confirm the choice.
- Finally, go to the *reboot system now* option and select it.

Your device will boot now and it might take a longer time than it does usually. When it completely boots up, it should be on the downgraded firmware you installed. Cheers!

---

<sup>Please do this at your own risk. More details on this method can be found [here](http://droidviews.com/2013/how-to-downgrade-firmware-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/).</sup>